# Netcore API not connect to MySQL RDS on AWS Lambda

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, aws-lambda, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I have api with netcore 3.1 in aws lambda that can't connect with mysql rds. Locally it works correctly but in aws lambda it doesn't.

I use entity framework. Scaffold-dbcontext with Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.Mysql.

The answer i get in postman is 504 api gateway timeout

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddDbContext<APIDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql("server=xxxxx.xxx.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com;database=db;user=admin;password=pass;"));
```

APIDbContext.cs:

```
public APIDbContext()
{
}

public APIDbContext(DbContextOptions<APIDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
{
}

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseMySql("server=xxxxx.xxx.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com;database=db;user=admin;password=pass;");
    }
```

Testing I did the following and if it worked:

```
string dataString = "";

MySqlConnectionStringBuilder cnString = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();

cnString.Server = "xxxxx.xxx.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com";
cnString.UserID = "admin";
cnString.Password = "pass";
cnString.Database = "db";
cnString.Port = 3306;

using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(cnString.ToString()))
{
    conn.Open();

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Office FROM offices LIMIT 1", conn);

    using (MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            dataString = dr["Office"].ToString();
        }
    }
}

return Ok(dataString);
```

file.csproj

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AWS.Logger.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.SecretsManager" Version="3.3.103.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.Targets" Version="3.1.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer" Version="5.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="10.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup" Version="3.3.101" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.S3" Version="3.3.111.37" />
    <PackageReference Include="HtmlSanitizer" Version="5.0.343" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.6">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="3.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.6">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="3.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="3.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" Version="5.2.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.OData.Client" Version="7.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Design" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="106.11.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="SendGrid" Version="9.20.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="3.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Environment" Version="2.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Thread" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" Version="3.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft" Version="5.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore" Version="3.0.57" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Why doesn't it work with the settings I have in startup.cs and apidbcontext.cs?

Thank you very much for the help.

Update:

Following @lauxjpn recommendation to print the connection string, I read it like this:

```
    public class OfficesCatalogsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly APIDbContext _context;
        private readonly ILogger<OfficesCatalogsController> _logger;

        public OfficesCatalogsController(APIDbContext context, ILogger<OfficesCatalogsController> logger)
        {
            _context = context;
            _logger = logger;
        }

    
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllOffices()
        {
        
        try
            {

                _logger.LogInformation("Logeando ando inicio try");

                var cxn = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString;

                _logger.LogInformation("ConnString: " + cxn);
                
                
                var query = (from office in _context.Officescatalog
                             select new
                             {
                                 office.IdOffice,
                                 office.Office
                             });

                var result = await query.ToListAsync();

                if (result == null) return NotFound();

                _logger.LogInformation("Logeando ando fin try");
                return Ok(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Catch");
                _logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
                return new JsonResult(ex.Message) { StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError };
            }
        }
    }
```

In cloudwatch I never see the connection string print out, but if I run it on my local machine and connection string to the rds db, it works perfectly

Cloudwatch logs:

```
2020-08-08T10:52:32.828-05:00
START RequestId: ce1e574e-efc1-42f5-8da1-76a834ee Version: $LATEST

2020-08-08T10:52:32.828-05:00
[40m[1m[33mwarn[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.EphemeralXmlRepository[50]

2020-08-08T10:52:32.829-05:00
Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage.

2020-08-08T10:52:32.829-05:00
[Warning] Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.EphemeralXmlRepository: Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage.

2020-08-08T10:52:32.829-05:00
[Warning] Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager: Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits.

2020-08-08T10:52:32.829-05:00
[40m[1m[33mwarn[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[59]

2020-08-08T10:52:32.838-05:00
Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits.

2020-08-08T10:52:32.838-05:00
[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[58]

2020-08-08T10:52:32.839-05:00
Creating key {7875e158-x} with creation date 2020-08-08 15:52:32Z, activation date 2020-08-08 15:52:32Z, and expiration date 2020-11-06 15:52:32Z.

2020-08-08T10:52:32.858-05:00
[Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager: Creating key {7875e158-x} with creation date 2020-08-08 15:52:32Z, activation date 2020-08-08 15:52:32Z, and expiration date 2020-11-06 15:52:32Z.

2020-08-08T10:52:32.858-05:00
[40m[1m[33mwarn[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]

2020-08-08T10:52:32.859-05:00
No XML encryptor configured. Key {7875e158-x} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.

2020-08-08T10:52:33.367-05:00
[Warning] Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager: No XML encryptor configured. Key {7875e158-x} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.

2020-08-08T10:52:33.367-05:00
[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]

2020-08-08T10:52:33.368-05:00
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

2020-08-08T10:52:33.377-05:00
[Information] Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

2020-08-08T10:52:33.377-05:00
[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]

2020-08-08T10:52:33.377-05:00
Hosting environment: Production

2020-08-08T10:52:33.377-05:00
[Information] Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Hosting environment: Production

2020-08-08T10:52:33.378-05:00
[Information] Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Content root path: /var/task

2020-08-08T10:52:33.378-05:00
[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]

2020-08-08T10:52:33.378-05:00
Content root path: /var/task

2020-08-08T10:52:33.728-05:00
[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]

2020-08-08T10:52:33.728-05:00
Request starting GET https://xxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/offices 0

2020-08-08T10:52:33.766-05:00
[Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request starting GET https://xxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/offices 0

2020-08-08T10:52:34.548-05:00
[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]

2020-08-08T10:52:34.548-05:00
Executing endpoint 'API.Controllers.OfficesCatalogsController.GetAllOffices (PI)'

2020-08-08T10:52:34.566-05:00
[Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Executing endpoint 'API.Controllers.OfficesCatalogsController.GetAllOffices (API)'

2020-08-08T10:52:34.807-05:00
[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[3]

2020-08-08T10:52:34.807-05:00
Route matched with {action = "GetAllOffices", controller = "OfficesCatalogs"}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult] GetAllOffices() on controller API.Controllers.OfficesCatalogsController (API).

2020-08-08T10:52:34.808-05:00
[Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Route matched with {action = "GetAllOffices", controller = "OfficesCatalogs"}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult] GetAllOffices() on controller API.Controllers.OfficesCatalogsController (API).

2020-08-08T10:52:37.568-05:00
[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: API.Controllers.OfficesCatalogsController[0]

2020-08-08T10:52:37.568-05:00
Logeando ando

2020-08-08T10:52:37.585-05:00
[Information] API.Controllers.OfficesCatalogsController: Logeando ando

2020-08-08T10:52:37.585-05:00
[Information] API.Controllers.OfficesCatalogsController: Logeando ando inicio try

2020-08-08T10:52:37.585-05:00
[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: API.Controllers.OfficesCatalogsController[0]

2020-08-08T10:52:37.585-05:00
Logeando ando inicio try

2020-08-08T10:53:03.425-05:00
END RequestId: ce1e574e-efc1-42f5-8da1-76a834ee

2020-08-08T10:53:03.425-05:00
REPORT RequestId: ce1e574e-efc1-42f5-8da1-76a834ee Duration: 30028.08 ms Billed Duration: 30000 ms Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 256 MB Init Duration: 1865.88 ms

2020-08-08T10:53:03.425-05:00
2020-08-08T15:53:03.425Z ce1e574e-efc1-42f5-8da1-76a834ee Task timed out after 30.03 seconds

2020-08-08T10:53:04.869-05:00
[40m[1m[33mwarn[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.EphemeralXmlRepository[50]

2020-08-08T10:53:04.869-05:00
Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage.

2020-08-08T10:53:04.870-05:00
[Warning] Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.EphemeralXmlRepository: Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage.

2020-08-08T10:53:04.871-05:00
[40m[1m[33mwarn[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[59]

2020-08-08T10:53:04.871-05:00
Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits.

2020-08-08T10:53:04.871-05:00
[Warning] Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager: Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits.

2020-08-08T10:53:04.879-05:00
[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[58]

2020-08-08T10:53:04.879-05:00
Creating key {a531edfd-x} with creation date 2020-08-08 15:53:04Z, activation date 2020-08-08 15:53:04Z, and expiration date 2020-11-06 15:53:04Z.

2020-08-08T10:53:04.880-05:00
[Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager: Creating key {a531edfd-x} with creation date 2020-08-08 15:53:04Z, activation date 2020-08-08 15:53:04Z, and expiration date 2020-11-06 15:53:04Z.

2020-08-08T10:53:04.896-05:00
[40m[1m[33mwarn[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]

2020-08-08T10:53:04.896-05:00
No XML encryptor configured. Key {a531edf-x} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.

2020-08-08T10:53:04.897-05:00
[Warning] Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager: No XML encryptor configured. Key {a531edfd-x} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.

2020-08-08T10:53:05.359-05:00
[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]

2020-08-08T10:53:05.359-05:00
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

2020-08-08T10:53:05.360-05:00
[Information] Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

2020-08-08T10:53:05.368-05:00
[Information] Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Hosting environment: Production

2020-08-08T10:53:05.368-05:00
[Information] Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Content root path: /var/task

2020-08-08T10:53:05.368-05:00
[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]

2020-08-08T10:53:05.368-05:00
Hosting environment: Production

2020-08-08T10:53:05.368-05:00
[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]

2020-08-08T10:53:05.368-05:00
Content root path: /var/task
```

LambdaEntryPoint.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace API
{

    public class LambdaEntryPoint :

    
        Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction
    {
  
        protected override void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
        }

     
        protected override void Init(IHostBuilder builder)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

LocalEntryPoint.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace API
{

public class LocalEntryPoint
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

Will I have to configure something from the lambda entry point or something similar for the connection to be loaded in aws lambda?

Comment: Please post the actual full exception that is being thrown (you might need to set the connection timeout parameter to a lower value, so the MySQL connection times out before the web request does). Also, `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Design` is a very old and discontinued package. It is not compatible with current versions of Pomelo anymore (just remove it). Another way to further debug your issue is to log the actual connection string that is being used in Pomelo's internal `MySqlConnection`. That way you can be sure that it is exactly like the one from your successful manual test.

Comment: @lauxjpn Thanks for your answer. I already delete the package that you indicated to me and I read the grapefruit connection string as follows: 
`_context.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString;`

Checking the cloudwatch logs the connection is not printed

Comment: I post an answer that I will update over time once there is more information. In addition to that, you wrote that your manual connection using `MySqlConnection` worked. Did you run the code on the same server from the same code where EF Core fails to connect, or did you run the `MySqlConnection` code on your local machine?

Comment: @lauxjpn I have increased the timeout in my in the connectionstring and aws lambda and it has already worked correctly: `services.AddDbContext<APIDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql($"server=xxxxx.xxx.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com;database=db;user=admin;password=pass;ConnectionTimeout=60;"));`

Comment: So you mean it works when you increase the timeout to 60 seconds? How long does it actually take for the connection to get established?

Comment: Also, I updated my answer with how to use an interceptor to definitively get the connection string used for the database connection.

Comment: @lauxjpn I reduced the connection timeout to 45 seconds 
(in aws lambda too)and the response I get in postman average is: `Time: 375 ms Size: 3.58 KB`

if I set it for less than 45 seconds (
in aws lambda too), it gives me the 504 timeout error.

I do not understand why this happens if it is a simple query

Comment: That is very strange. If you set the timeout to less then 30 sec (say 5 sec), you should get an exception thrown by EF Core. I that the case?

Comment: I tried to reproduces your issue by creating an ASP.NET app using the `serverless.AspNetCoreWebAPI` template, added a `DbContext` and deployed it to AWS Lambda. I then setup an MySQL 8.0.17 RDS instance and then ran the app. I had no issues whatsoever. The app would always connect successfully to the RDS instance in a very short time and I never had to even configure the `ConnectionTimeout` connection string setting.

Comment: I also updated my answer with some connection pool related troubleshooting you should try.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfect!!!!

Comment: If the issue has not come back with correct connection pooling settings, jut mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

First fix your logging, so that the connection string actually gets output to the log. See [Logging in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core: Configure logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configure-logging) for how to setup your `appsettings.json` (or `appsettings.Production.json`) file to accomplish that.

It should look similar to this:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",

      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" : "Debug",
      "YourNamespace.OfficesCatalogsController": "Debug"
    }
  }
}
```

---

#### Update

Actually, the following line might open the connection, which then timeouts, which is why you never see the connection string in the log:

```cs
var cxn = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString;
```

To definitely get the actual connection string, you could use an interceptor:

```cs
public class ConnectionInterceptor : DbConnectionInterceptor
{
    public override InterceptionResult ConnectionOpening(DbConnection connection, ConnectionEventData eventData, InterceptionResult result)
    {
        // TODO:
        // Log the connection string here.
        
        return base.ConnectionOpening(connection, eventData, result);
    }

    public override Task<InterceptionResult> ConnectionOpeningAsync(DbConnection connection, ConnectionEventData eventData, InterceptionResult result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        // TODO:
        // Log the connection string here.

        return base.ConnectionOpeningAsync(connection, eventData, result, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

You can configure it like this:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<APIDbContext>(
    options => options
        .UseMySql("server=xxxxx.xxx.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com;database=db;user=admin;password=pass;")
        .AddInterceptors(new ConnectionInterceptor()));
```

---

#### Update

It is also possible, that if you have connection pooling enabled (which by default keeps 100 connections per same connection string opened), that you could exceed the max connections setup for the RDS instance.

To test this, add `Pooling=false` to your connection string and restart your RDS instance.

If you can suddenly connect without issues after that, then this behavior might have been the issue.